# CKEditor 5, jQuery - find and replace text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

How could I find and replace text in [CKEditor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) 5 using JavaScript and jQuery?

I want to find special character '@' in the text and replace all characters after '@' and '@' character too on my own text.

I am using *change:data*...

```
window.editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `editor.getData()` and `editor.setData()`, then use Regex `@\w+&nbsp;` to match `@`, `alphanumeric` and `space`, without matching space it only work on paste but you can't type `@user` because when typing `@u` it will replaced with `newString`

the example below

```js
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
  .then(editor => {
    editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
      let content = editor.getData();
      if (/@\w+(&nbsp;|\s)/gi.test(content)) {
        content = content.replace(/@\w+(&nbsp;|\s)/gi, 'newString ')
        editor.setData(content)
      }
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div id="editor"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a sound solution, as it trigger an infinite loop... if the if statement is true, the .setData function triggers the .on listener infinitely.